# Passing two different list from controller to view through Ajax Success in MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to pass two different list from controller to view using ajax success.

My Ajax Code is

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "@Url.Action("GetDoctorWiseReport","DCDReport")",
     data: { fromDate: fromDate, toDate: toDate },
     type: "post",
     datatype: "json",
     success: function (data) {
       // do something
    }
```

My Controller Code is

```
 public JsonResult GetDoctorwiseReport(DateTime fromDate,DateTime toDate)
    {
        IEnumerable<DoctorVM> Doctors = homeObj.GetDistinctDoctorsFromTransactionMaster(fromDate, toDate);
        IEnumerable<WorkOrderDetailsVM> woDetails = homeObj.GetDoctorwiseReport(fromDate, toDate);
        return Json(woDetails.ToList());
    }
```

I want to pass both Doctors and WoDetails through Json.

Comment: `return Json(new { x = woDetails, y = Doctors });`

Comment: As Stephen says, return one object with two variables - each one containing one of the lists. Really the same concept as you would employ with a viewmodel.

Comment: Yes , return Json(new { x = woDetails, y = Doctors }); This works. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stephen Muecke said

```
return Json(new { x = woDetails, y = Doctors });
```

This works fine.